# I need to get value of text box which is keyword and on click link will redirect

Tags: jquery, html

I need to work this code out with jquery.

I need to get value of text box which is keyword and on click link will redirect.

So i am having difficulty getting that value from text box and then run the redirect. which is this line  `$("#serviceorder").val("keyword");`

**HTML code :**

```
<html>
<input id="serviceorder" type="text" data-bind="value: keyword" />
<a href="" id="g-search-button"></a>
</html>
```

**JS code :**

```
$("#g-search-button").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                        $("#serviceorder").val("keyword");      
                    var keyword = event.currentTarget.value;

                if (keyword.length > 0) {
                    window.location.href = "URL + encodeURIComponent(keyword);
                    return false;               
                }
            });
```

Comment: `$('#element').val("some text");` is used to **set** the value of *element* to *some text* - not to **get** the value.

Comment: ok then how i will get the value

Comment: You should probably reread the docs on [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/), since getting the value is the simplest thing you can do with that function

Comment: Try `$("#g-search-button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var keyword = $.trim($("#serviceorder").val());
    if (keyword.length > 0) {
        window.location.href = "myurl?keyword=" + encodeURIComponent(keyword);
    }
});`

Comment: @what is the url you would like to be redirected after click on link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be redirected to a url for example: https://stackoverflow.com/keywordHere

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#g-search-button").click(function (event) {
    var URL='http://stackoverflow.com';//change this as you want
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var keyword =  $("#serviceorder").val();
                    if (keyword.length > 0) {
                        window.location.href = URL +'/'+ encodeURIComponent(keyword);
                    }
                });
    });
```